# Define and Remove outliers from a Pareto-like Distribution

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, inference, outliers

I currently have a set of data:

```
1     40950
2     27749
3     14786
.........
15       95
16       75
..........
12205    1
15344    1
19991    1
```

The first column is the "length", and the second column is the frequency of the "length" data. In other words, for length 1, it occurs 40950 in the dataset, and for extreme values such as length 19991, it occurs only 1 time in the dataset. The distribution is heavy-tailed and right-skewed, also the x-axis(the first column) is very sparse after the number 200 (and the frequency is very low). I think the distribution does resemble Pareto distribution by doing a goodness-of-fit test.
[image]

The rough visualization looks like this: [image]
I set the x-lim to be only 50 at this point but it lingers to a much larger number (max: 19991). The variance of the data is very high due to this.
However, my major goal is to exclude some of the instances with high lengths. For example, I want to remove the instance with a length of 12205 and the instance with a length of 15344. The problem is, ideally, I do not want to set a random threshold/quantile, stating a fixed portion of instances I'd like to keep; I'd like to have a more rigorous way of defining the outliers. Do you think there are possible methods for me to try at this moment?

Comment: Trying to solve this thresholding thing looks suspiciously like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) as it is difficult to imagine anyone finding a threshold to be of any interest *per se* to an organization or scientific endevour. More likely the threshold is meant to solve an related problem. Instead of throwing away data, why not model it as a Pareto distribution? What are you trying to do with this data?

Comment: I'm just attempting to remove data points with large lengths. In my context, such data points do not provide valuable information and thus shall be removed before doing some NLP tasks. It's basically asking if there are more mathematically regirous way to define and remove outliers from a Pareto distribution.

Comment: "I'm just attempting to remove data points with large lengths" - for what purpose? You have a distributional model for which MLE will strongly downweight large observations already. On what basis is hard removal better than that? I agree with Galen, it sounds like an XY problem - it lokks like the real issue isn't removal of outliers at all, it's avoiding low-information points dragging your model fit around with them.  Removal of 'outliers' is not usually the best way to tackle that issue